# Use listAgg with H2 db in Grails

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, hql, dialect

I have a grails application. We support Oracle db and H2 db.

I'm using Oracle 11g DB on prod and H2 DB on dev environment.
I have hibernate query with "listAgg" function. It works fine on Oracle.
But H2 doesn't support this function. What can I do to use this function with H2 also?

I think it can be done through custom dialect. But I do not understand how. Can anyone explain in detail?

I see H2 has 'group_concat' function that is similar to listAgg. Can I configure my application so that the 'group_concat' used for H2DB instead of listAgg.

Grails 2.3.11.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`LISTAGG` is function specific to Oracle. You will not be able to use it in other databases. For example in MSSQL alternative could be to use `STUFF` function.

If you need it in H2, you would have to define user-defined function with this name which does the same what LISTAGG does in Oracle. See http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions for details

Comment: Thanks for your response! But i want to use it with grails and hibernate, not native sql.

Comment: Doesn't this work? https://bhavikablog.wordpress.com/2012/12/07/adding-custom-function-in-hibernate-with-custom-dialects/

Comment: I have problem with 'within' part of ListAgg oracle function. How can i define it?